# How to create bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have an `application.yml` file:

```
queue:
  connection:
    username: user
    password: user1
```

And I am including another library which contains `Settings.java` class:

```
public class Settings {
    private String user;
    private String password;
    ...
    // getters, setters
}
```

I haven't the opportunity to change the Settings class. 
I want to do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class SpringConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "queue.connection")
    public Settings settings() {
        return new Settings();  // Instance was created but without properties from application.yml
    }
}
```

How can I do create bean the Settings with properties from an `application.yml` file?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define separate class for properties that wraps `Settings`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "queue")
public class QueueConnectionProperties {
    private Settings connection = new Settings(); 
    // no-args constructor, getter & setter
}
```

Also, just adding `@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueueConnectionProperties.class)` will create properties bean for you, hence no need to create bean explicitly. E.g. following will be enough:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueueConnectionProperties.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

If you want to have one global properties you can define following:

```
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppProperties {

    private QueueConnectionProperties queue = new Queue();
    // other properties

    // no-args constructor, getter & setter

    public static class QueueConnectionProperties {
        private Settings connection = new Settings(); 
        // no-args constructor, getter & setter
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class AppConfig {
}
```

<sub>Note: notice, that names of the fields (`queue`, `connection`) and properties nesting reflects `yaml`.</sub>

Also, you are not forced to define all properties in single class. You can list multiple classes in `@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties1.class, AppProperties2.class, AppProperties3.class})`

Comment: Thanks, Can I create GlobalSettingsFile and add to all objects to configure? And how can I do?

Comment: @Oleg I've updated the answer: basically you can define one `AppProperties` class and add all other properties to it (for example as static classes). Then just add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)` on your `@Configuration` class.

Comment: @Oleg Also you're not actually forced to have all properties in single class. You can have multiple property classes. In this case just add `@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties1.class, AppProperties2.class, AppProperties3.class})`

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You could extend `Settings` since `@ConfigurationProperties` binding is based on setters which are hopefully `public`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "queue.connection")
public class AutoConfigurationSettings extends Settings {

}
```

As per [24.7.1 Loading YAML](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-loading-yaml):

> To bind to properties like that by using Spring Boot’s Binder utilities (which is what @ConfigurationProperties does), you need to have a property in the target bean of type java.util.List (or Set) and you either need to provide a setter or initialize it with a mutable value. For example, the following example binds to the properties shown previously:

Comment: Thanks for the help, Karol.